# Class Modifiers

Tags: c#, vb.net, class

I've never taken the initiative to learn the correct class modifier since it has always been a "nice to have" but not a "need to have".

It annoys me that I can do `Dim F as New Person.FavoriteFoodsList`.

Which class modifier do I use so that my Person class can utilize the FavoriteFoodsList but nothing outside of Person can instantiate the FavoriteFoodsList?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim P As New Person
    P.FavoriteFoods.Add("Pizza")
    Dim F As New Person.FavoriteFoodsList 'How do I prevent this
End Sub
Public Class Person
    Public FavoriteFoods As New FavoriteFoodsList
    Public Class FavoriteFoodsList
        Inherits Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
    End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you define a public interface for your class then mark the implementation as private.

```
Public Interface IFavoriteFoodsList
    Inherits Collections.Generic.IList(Of String)
    ' Define other public api methods'
End Interface

Public Class Person
    Public FavoriteFoods As IFavoriteFoodsList = New FavoriteFoodsList
    Private Class FavoriteFoodsList
        Inherits Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
        Implements IFavoriteFoodsList
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That did the trick!! I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me. It says I have to wait 3 more minutes

Comment: Actually, it is somewhat the same as phoog's answer.  You cannot instantiat FavoriteFoodsList from phoog's solution as well.  
However, I find this one a bit nicer, since the interface is defined outside the Person class, as where in phoog's answer, there's a nested public class, which isn't that 'friendly' imho.

Comment: In phoogs answer I can't add a food to the list. I tried P.FavoriteFoods.Add, there was no Add method available. *Edit, I guess since I didn't inherit the list?

Comment: That's because he forgot to inherit the FavoriteFoodList abstract class from List<String> - I've editted his C# code example.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels I agree that the nested public class is not so friendly; I was mostly trying to solve the pattern of the original question rather than trying to come up with the best solution.

Comment: BTW. I love stackoverflow, bunch of geniuses

Answer (score 2):

EDIT 3: removed earlier version of this answer that tried to apply the pattern below to private/protected members:

To illustrate how this would work across assembly boundaries, here's an example:

```
public class Person
{
    public abstract class FavoriteFoodsList : List<string>
    {
        //internal constructor prevents types in other assemblies from inheriting
        internal FavoriteFoodsList(){}
    }
    private class FFL2 : FavoriteFoodsList
    {
    }
    public FavoriteFoodsList FavoriteFoods = new FFL2();
}
```

Disclaimer, this is just a sketch to illustrate the accessibility issues; the field should be a property, etc.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and when I type P, I can see FavoriteFoods and FavoriteFoodsList. I'm not able to add anything to either

Comment: Sure you can see FavoriteFoodsList.  If you want to be able to use that class, the 'base' class has to be visible.

Comment: @DontFretBrett thanks for the translation; I've added it to the answer.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels but since the class is abstract, it can't be instantiated outside the class.  I just realized though that we need to prevent outsiders from *inheriting* from the class as well; I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: @DontFretBrett you couldn't add anything to the FavoriteFoodsList instances because I forgot to derive FavoriteFoodsList from `List<string>`.  But the only way to do this is either with `internal` or with an interface.  The `internal` approach prevents code from other assemblies from instantiating the class, but it doesn't prevent other types in the same assembly from doing so.

Comment: Thanks yeah I realized that after I commented. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no class modifier or accessibility modifier that will let you accomplish this within one assembly. An interface with a private implementation class, as the other answerer said, is probably the best solution.

However, if you're writing a class library, you can declare all of FavoriteFoodsList's constructors as `internal` (`Friend` in VB, I think), and that will prevent other assemblies from constructing their own FavoriteFoodsList objects.

Comment: I'll try that out next time I'm doing something like that. Thanks!